# Inserting a Pricing Formula

Tags: cognito-forms

If my company uses an exponentially regressive unit pricing model for quantity discounts (e.g. (P*Q)-(0.5^Q)), is there a way to do this in Cognito Forms? The only exponential option I see is tied to e.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the link describing all of the mathematical operations you can do in [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com):

https://www.cognitoforms.com/support/50/calculations/numeric-calculations

In this case you are specifically looking for `Math.Pow`, which will allow you to use 0.5 instead of E.